# Wsimport directory must be set in global preferences - Ready! API

Tags: import, wsdl, jax-ws, soapui, preferences

I import a wsdl file in Ready! API. Now I want to generate the code for JAX-WS artifacts, but I am always getting the following message:

```
Wsimport directory must be set in global preferences
```

I am using Ubuntu, if I run the command `wsimport` from the terminal is working properly.

In the `Tools` menu I try to configure the preference using the `paht for Java` but is not working,there I am getting this error:

```
Could not find wsimport script at MY_PATH for java
```

What I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

you set your java_home directory or use this command

/home/java7/bin/wsimport